# RestSharp HttpBasicAuthentication - example

Tags: c#, authentication, restsharp

I have a WPF client using RestSharp and WEB API Service. I try to use `HttpBasicAuthenticator` as follows:

```
RestRequest login = new RestRequest("/api/users/login", Method.POST);
var authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin","22");
authenticator.Authenticate(Client, login);
IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(login);
```

The POST request looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost/api/users/login HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MjI=
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.1.0.0
Host: dellnote:810
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

1. How do I process this field, `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MjI=` on the server side?  Do I get username and password from this header?
2. How do I return security token from server to client and save it on the client side?

I need to get simple authentication based on security token but cannot find  example that describes all sides of this process. Can someone point me to some full example that includes client and server side (and uses RestSharp).

Comment: You can see my answer below

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Answer (score 69):

`new SimpleAuthenticator("username", username, "password", password)` did **NOT** work with me.

The following however worked:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 9):

From RestSharp documentation:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("username", "foo", "password", "bar");

var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);
```

The URL generated for this request would be http://example.com/resource?username=foo&password=bar

So you get the password just as any other parameter (although, it's recommended to use POST method then GET, for security reasons).

As for the cookies, check this out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.setcookie.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.getcookie.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: What about my second question?

Comment: I think cookies is the way to go, for that

Comment: I've thought about using CookieContainer and FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method. But it's more like a browser way (and I have WPF client). I'm not sure that cookies is the right way.

Comment: As far as I know you can use cookies with WPF. I've added links in the answer

Comment: It should be noted that the above code will fail if you don't include "using RestSharp.Authenticators" at the top, or just replace "SimpleAuthenticator" with "RestSharp.Authenticators.SimpleAuthenticator".

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me:

```
private string GetBearerToken()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin", "22");
    var request = new RestRequest("api/users/login", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\" }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var responseJson = _client.Execute(request).Content;
    var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["access_token"].ToString();
    if(token.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException("API authentication failed.");
    }
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To date, most of the examples above were how I used to do it. However this morning I updated to version 109.0.1 and discovered that they had deprecated `RestClient.Authenticator` and now use `RestClientOptions.Authenticator` like so:

```
string baseUrl = "https://yoururl.com";
var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl);
options.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");

var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
restClient.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin","22");

RestRequest login = new RestRequest("/api/users/login", Method.POST);
IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(login);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it; never post code on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer your first question about retrieval of Auth Header values (Server Side) from [How can I retrieve Basic Authentication credentials from the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855698/how-can-i-retrieve-basic-authentication-credentials-from-the-header):

```
private UserLogin GetUserLoginCredentials()
{
    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    UserLogin userLogin;
    string authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
    {
        string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));
        int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

        userLogin = new UserLogin()
        {
            Username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex),
            Password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1)
        };
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle what happens if that isn't the case
        throw new Exception("The authorization header is either empty or isn't Basic.");
    }
    return userLogin;
}
```

Usage of this method might be:

```
UserLogin userLogin = GetUserLoginCredentials();
```

Also have a look at: [A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter)

Alternative answer on second question about returning the token (Server Side):

```
var httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse();

TokenResponse tokenResponse;
bool wasAbleToGetAccesToken = _identityServerHelper.TryGetAccessToken(userLogin.Username, userLogin.Password,
            platform, out tokenResponse);

httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = wasAbleToGetAccesToken ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
httpResponseMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenResponse),
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

return httpResponseMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The new way of doing it in following. Add the authenticator as an options.

One option

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("http://example.com") {
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password")
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Another option

```
var request = new RestRequest("/api/users/me") {
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password")
};
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

See more here https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#basic-authentication