# Get OAuth2.0 Bearer Token from AuthURL and ClientID

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, postman, bearer-token

In Postman I am able to generate the Bearer token using

1. Callback URL
2. Auth URL
3. Client ID

How do I do the same using C# code?

This is the code I am running but the response body does not have the bearer token.

```
var client = new RestClient("AuthURL"); 
var requestToken = new RestRequest(Method.POST); 
requestToken.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); 
requestToken.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
requestToken.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123", ParameterType.RequestBody); 
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(requestToken);

string res = response.Content;
```

Comment: What does the response contain? Some sort of error maybe?

Comment: the request is successful but the response does not have the bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

where is your username and password?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);
```

might be a duplicate of this question
[RestSharp HttpBasicAuthentication - example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833431/restsharp-httpbasicauthentication-example)