# .net web api - Authorization header is always null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on an old (.net 4.7) Web api project. I don't care about authenticating the user as this is done upstream but i need to read the Authorization header to get some user details from a JWT.
I haven't added any auth code etc so i was hoping i could just get the JWT from the Authorization header.

Basic code

```
var requestHeaders = Request.Headers;
requestHeaders.TryGetValues("Authorization", out IEnumerable<string> jwtToken);
```

Why is jwtToken null ?

Postman request
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retrieve Basic Authentication credentials from the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855698/how-can-i-retrieve-basic-authentication-credentials-from-the-header)

Comment: Add bearer with a space before the token

Comment: it is strange that you try to convert to IEnumerable<string>, I think it should be string or 
StringValues

Answer (score 1):

Issue was getting the headers from the request message instead of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers`

Comment: I had two webhooks with the same authentication code running. One worked, one found an empty parameter. Changing from Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameters to HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"] solved the issue. Thanks!