# Blazor WASM post from Client cs code to Server controller

Tags: post, server, controller, blazor, client

I am developing a Blazor WASM application in .NET6.

In Blazor is possible to make a call from Client component

```
@code {
   await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Model>("/api/model/view/" + modelId);
}
```

that triggers a controller in the Server project

```
[HttpGet, Route("/api/model/view/{id:int}")]
public async Task<Model> GetModel(int modelId)
{
    try { return await Task.FromResult(_IModel.GetModel(id)); }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

But is it possible to post from a client project via cs class like following:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authcookie_value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
httpClient.BaseAddress = new(Parameters.urlstring);
var result = httpClient.PostAsync("/api/auth/refresh", content);
```

And the controller on the Server project to be fired:

```
[HttpPost, Route("/api/auth/refresh")]
public IActionResult AuthRefresh(StringContent httpContent)
{
   try
   {
   }
   catch { throw; }
}
```

The above example is not working because the controller is not fired when the call is thiggered.
Any ideas?

Comment: How are you mapping and using `modelId`?

Comment: modelId is an integer, and the first scenario is working

Comment: You're stating that the first scenario works, but that is incorrect. Your URLs won't match. Update the question with the correct endpoint for getting a model via ID.

Comment: This looks like custom authentication. I suggest using the HTTP header to refresh your session, not a POST HTTP request. Your token should be sent using the headers and stored in a reusable `HttpClient` from `DependencyInjection`. Then on each request to the API you can refresh the token using middleware.

Comment: @Marius Thanks Marius, indeed i made a mistake while describing the first scenario, I have correct it now. Do you have an example with HTTP header on request for authentication?

Comment: Here are SO links: Add header to `HttpClient`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient | Reading the header and a bit extra: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855698/how-can-i-retrieve-basic-authentication-credentials-from-the-header | Remember that when it comes to security, you can always learn more and improve.

Comment: Middleware example, and my suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977088/asp-net-core-web-api-authentication